# Tuning nnet package in R to converge faster

Tags: r, neural-network, backpropagation

I am working on my research and am stuck for a long time on getting the weights to converge in nnet package. I am running back propagation algorithm on weather data to predict temperature. I previously used neuralnet package and weights converged very well. I was able to increase the number of iterations to increase accuracy. But neuralnet package is extremely slow when I increase the input pattern size. Below is brief explanation about the data.

I collect weather data every 1 hour from a station. I pad every 1 hour data for 24 hours into a row. This forms my input pattern. Neuralnet runs beautifully and converges for one months data, which is around 653 patterns. Now when I want to train the same with one year. Neuralnet seems to run for ages.

I hence opted to nnet. nnet is very quick. But it does not converge as neuralnet.
Below are the code snippets I used.

```
formula.in=V385+V386+....+V392~V1+V2+...+V382+V383+V384

net<-neuralnet(formula=formula.in,data=data,hidden=90,threshold=0.0001,act.fct="tanh",err.fct="sse", algorithm = "rprop+")
```

As you see here, I can change the threshold to get desired convergence. 
Now My nnet snippet is (this is the one that was quicker but does not allow me to change the convergence threshold.

```
target<-as.matrix(data[,385:392]);
input<-as.matrix(data[,1:384]);
net<-nnet(input,target,size=2,maxit=15000)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Hi, have you solve it? i have the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: From where you downloaded those packages?

Comment: Hi Yura, I used install.packages("nnet") to install nnet package. It downloads it from the following location http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/nnet_7.3-9.zip

Comment: Hi Gabriela, Sorry for the late reply. Yes I fixed it. But not by manipulating the code. I analysed the data more and got rid of bunch of data points that were just slowing the system. I do not have any general solution to this problem right now

Answer (score 0):

i am also using R for neural networks. As i am a beginner so, please pardon me if my point sounds bit silly. As you said, you are using back-propagation algorithm to train the network, but as far as i know, nnet only implements a single layer Feed Forward neural network unlike neuralnet.

In short, i think nnet is not using back-propagation. Kindly correct me if i am wrong.